# CakePHP - how to use Helpers to make an image link with target="_blank"

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This seems like it should be simple, but I'm new to CakePHP.  Maybe it's just something I should write in good ole HTML, but - was hoping to find out how do to this with CakePHP's HTML helper.

I just want an image link that has target="_blank".

This is what I tried:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('tmp/728x90.jpg',
    array('alt'=>'advertisement', 'height'=>'90', 
    'width'=>'728')),'http://www.google.com', array('target'=>'_blank')); ?>
```

(all in one line - just broke up for ease of viewing)

But when I do this, I get this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">&lt;img src=&quot;/img/tmp/728x90.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;advertisement&quot; height=&quot;90&quot; width=&quot;728&quot; /&gt;</a>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

**Answer** (thanks deceze)

```
<?php 

$image = $this->Html->image(
    'tmp/300x600.jpg', 
    array(
        'alt'=>'advertisement', 
        'height'=>'600', 
        'width'=>'300'
    )
);

echo $this->Html->link(
    $image,
    'http://www.google.com', 
    array(
        'target'=>'_blank', 
        'escape' => false
    )
); ?>
```

Comment: Answer is very useful, thanks for sharing. keep it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell `HtmlHelper::link` not to HTML escape the input.
This is all very well [documented in the manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20111220210043/http://book.cakephp.org/view/1442/link).

Answer (score 12):

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('fb2.jpg',array('alt'=>'facebook', 'height'=>'90','width'=>'728')),'http://www.facebook.com', array('target'=>'_blank','escape'=>false)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact code will be like this

```
  <?php 
         echo $this->Html->link(
                    $this->Html->image('tmp/728x90.jpg',
                                         array(
                                        'alt'=>'advertisement', 'height'=>'90',
                                        'width'=>'728')
                                       ),
                                    'http://www.google.com',
                                    array(
                                       'target'=>'_blank',
                                       'escape'=>false)
                                ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Html->image . Check it out:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1441/image

Comment: I have used that - and in fact, I'm using it in my code above.  Please give an example if I'm doing something wrong - the link you gave has no information regarding the target attribute for a link.

Comment: It's right in the manual:     <?php echo $this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", array(
    "alt" => "Brownies",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'recipes', 'action' => 'view', 6)
    )); ?>
You see you use the url option instead of the calling html->image inside of image->link

Comment: @user470714 - While I do appreciate your attempt at answering, I recommend reading the question before answering next time.  I did not ask how to make a linked image - I asked how to make a linked image open in a new tab/window with target="_blank".  Neither your answer, nor your comment addressed my question.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the Cook Book, you can use the 'url' option of the image method:

```
echo $this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", array(
   'alt' => "Brownies",
   'url' => array('controller' => 'recipes', 'action' => 'view', 6)
));
```

Answer (score -1):

echo $html->link("more",array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index/welcome'), array('style'=>'_blank'), false, false);?> image('more-arrow.png', array('alt' => 'more','height'=>'11','width'=>'17'))?>

Comment: I don't think that is right.   For one, it's got two php close tags, and two, it's setting "style" to _blank instead of target.  I appreciate your taking the time to answer but this question has already been answered. :)

Comment: :] I'm having a good laugh looking at this code. Nice refresher from the hectic day.